# preg_replace a part of a string with variable

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string that looks a little something like this:

```
$string = 'var1=foo&var2=bar&var3=blahblahblah&etc=etc';
```

And I would like to make another string from that, and replace it with a value, so for example it will look like this

```
$newstring = 'var1=foo&var2=bar&var3=$myVariable&etc=etc';
```

so var3 in the new string will be the value of `$myVariable`.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

No need for regex; built in URL functions should work more reliably.

```
// Parse the url first
$url = parse_url($string);

// Parse your query string into an array
parse_str($url['query'], $qs);

// Replace the var3 key with your variable
$qs['var3'] = $myVariable;

// Convert the array back into a query string
$url['query'] = http_build_query($qs);

// Convert the $url array back into a URL
$newstring = http_build_url($url);
```

Check out [`http_build_query`](http://www.php.net/http_build_query) and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str). This will append a var3 variable even if there isn't one, it will URL encode `$myVariable`, and its more readable than using `preg_replace`.

Comment: Well, my string actually has a URL in it; 

http://example.com/page?var1=foo&var2=bar&var3=$myVariable&etc=etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php) for that. Here comes an example

```
<?php

$string = 'var1=foo&var2=bar&var3=blahblahblah&etc=etc';
$var = 'foo';

echo preg_replace('/var3=(.*)&/', 'var3=' . $var . '&', $string);
```